# Linking against Shared Library, calling program without custom LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, awesomium

I can successfully link against `libawesomium-1.6.5.so` :

```
-L-L.
-L-lawesomium-1.6.5
-L-ldl
```

`libawesomium-1.6.5.so` is in the same directory as my executable, now if I try to call my program (I'll call it prog for now), it exists with:

```
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I make a symlink `libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0` pointing to `libawesomium-1.6.5.so`, running `prog` again gives me the same error, calling it with a custom `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./` works, but I wanna distribute `prog` and I want the user to be able to use `prog` with out root-rights (installing awesomium to `/usr/lib` etc.) and without the need of setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. One option would be a shell script which sets the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I would prefer a different way (I also heared setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a bad idea).

Furthermore, it would be great if there was no need to create the symlink to `libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0`.

**EDIT:**

Passing `-rpath=.` to the linker works! But unfortunatly awesomium can't deal with it:

```
/.../awesomium_test/AwesomiumProcess: error while loading shared libraries: libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Using -rpath and setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH from inside prog works**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use gcc, you can pass `-Wl,-rpath=lib_directory` in order to make the executable to search the libraries in the directory `lib_directory`.

Moreover, this argument accepts a special value `$ORIGIN` that represents the directory containing the executed program. So if you pass `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'` to gcc you will be able to keep `libawesomium-1.6.5.so` in the same directory than the program.

Comment: I figured it out! I can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before loading awesomium inside my program.

Comment: You should pass `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'` instead of `-Wl,-rpath=.` and LI_LIBRARY_PATH will be useless.

Comment: Passing `-rpath='$ORIGIN'` doesn't solve the problem: `AwesomiumProcess` is a different executable shipped with awesomium. I think it's used to create rendering threads. So I still have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because . is not in your path. Your options are to distribute a bash script which runs the binary with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set, as you say, or to copy the shared object to /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib or wherever suitable on that particular platform.

There is really no shortcut, unless you want to link statically.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid both ways. Thanks for making clear that there is no other way. Statically linking doesn't work, because there is no static lib for awesomium (closed source, only .so is provided)